# TeamCity migration without build history

Tags: teamcity

We use TeamCity 10.0.4 (build 42538) and want to migrate to the latest version (2022.04) with all our build configurations but without the build history. We saw here https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/how-to.html#Copy+Manually that:

> If you want to do a quick check and do not need to preserve the build
> history on the new server, you can skip Step 6 (cloning database) and
> all the optional items of Step 4.

Unfortunately by doing this manual copy we were not able to run the new instance without cloning the database, as we got the error on the image below.
[image]

We then did a "Restore from backup" (from the image below) by doing a "TeamCity Backup" (Administration > Backup > Run Backup) of the server settings, projects and builds configurations, with no more success.
[image]

Do you know a way to migrate to a newer TeamCity version by keeping all the build configurations and removing the entire build history ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to export/import current projects:

1. Export  to zip archive via Actions button or manually backup teamcity_data_dir/config/projects folder
2. Install fresh new TeamCity server
3. Copy your backup to teamcity_data_dir/config/projects